# RSelenium selecting an xpath with dynamic id

Tags: r, selenium, xpath, dynamic, rselenium

I'm working with the RSelenium package and have come across a hiccup I cannot find a way around. I'm trying to select an element from a table on a webpage and click on it, which I normally would do with

```
remdr$findElment('xpath',*insertxpathhere*)$clickElement()
```

Where remdr is the remote session. The problem I'm running into is that the xpath of the element I'm trying to select changes each time the page loads up. I've reloaded the page 3 times and copied the element's xpath below so you can see how it changes.

```
//*[@id="libraryPicker-1529934941230-datasets"]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]

//*[@id="libraryPicker-1529936019517-datasets"]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]

//*[@id="libraryPicker-1529936071347-datasets"]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]
```

As you can see, the 13 digit number changes each time the page loads up, and does not appear to have any discernable pattern which would allow me to make a bunch of dummy xpaths and check to see if one works. I have considered using a wildcard element (like //*[@id="libraryPicker-*wildcardelement*) but cannot find a way to do that in R. The css selector for this element is also dynamic in the same way.

I need some way to identify this element each time I run the script, despite it changing its xpath identifier every time.

Would anyone be able to help me with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code trials to identify the element you can use the following *xpath*:

```
//*[starts-with(@id,'libraryPicker')][contains(@id,'datasets')]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]
```